# Is there any similar library to RXAndroid in iOS

Tags: ios, rx-android

Is there any library or API in iOS similar to RX Android ?
API that I can use to call multiple requests at the same time and combine the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read about RxSwift https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift